# Como utilizar o show/hide dentro de um foreach em PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, foreach

Ao utilizar o script abaixo ele mascara apenas a primeira linha (se eu filtrar ou buscar ele até muda o que fica em primeiro, mas mascara apenas o primeiro de cima). Alguém pode me auxiliar?

HTML:

```
@foreach($senhas as $key => $value)
<tr>
<td>
 <form>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input id="password-field" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{ $value->senha }}">
   <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>
  </div>
 </form>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".toggle-password").click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
  var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
  if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: HTML:<td> 
 <form>
  <div class="form-group">
   <input id="password-field" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{ $value->senha }}">
   <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>            
  </div>
 </form>         
</td>

Comment: Tem certeza que sua pergunta é sobre PHP e foreach? Parece ser sobre JS. Por favor, verifique se postou as tags corretas ou se postou a pergunta correta.

Comment: Onde você está fazendo o foreach?

Comment: Acabei de atualizar o post.. obrigada pelas observações. Podem me auxiliar?

Comment: Troque a linha por `var input = $(this).prev();`... e não repita o `<form>` dentro do foreach.

Comment: @Sam funcionou perfeitamente!! Obrigada <3

Comment: Tem como eu fazer ele ficar exibindo apenas por X segundos?

Comment: Alterei a resposta com o tempo que vc pediu (2000 = 2 segundos).

Comment: Perfeito!! Muitíssimo obrigado. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está repetindo a `id="password-field"` em vários inputs. Com isso o código considera apenas o primeiro que encontrar. Lembre-se que o mesmo `id` não pode ser repetido na mesma página, ele deve ser único.

Uma solução é você buscar o elemento antes do ícone com `.prev()`, que é o `input`. Daí você não precisa usar nem `id` e nem o atributo `toggle` como está fazendo. E não precisa usar a tag `<form>` já que ela não tem nenhuma utilidade pelo código mostrado.

Veja como ficaria:

```js
$(".toggle-password").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
  var input = $(this).prev();
  if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
    input.attr("type", "text");
    setTimeout(function(){
       input.attr("type", "password");
       $this.toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    input.attr("type", "password");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table>
   <tr>
      <td> 
           <div class="form-group">
               <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{ $value->senha }}">
               <span class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>            
           </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td> 
           <div class="form-group">
               <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{ $value->senha }}">
               <span class="fa fa-fw fa-eye field-icon toggle-password"></span>            
           </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!! Obrigado ;)